# Vector in c++ using for loop

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am new to c++ in general. So I have been trying to learn about using vectors after someone recently helped with using an Arduino type project to read RFID tags. It really got me thinking I have no clue how to program. So I hit the books!

So here is the question: When I do the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Runner{
    char runnerTag[32];
    uint32_t ts;
};

std::vector<Runner > runners;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, Runners!\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::string runnertg = "testTrackTag01";
        uint32_t timeStamp = rand() % 100 + 1;
        runners[i] = new Runner({runnertg, timeStamp});
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this annoying little message from xcode:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'Runner'
```

on line 16 of the above snippet. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answer is in the error description.

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is?

Answer (score 3):

1. The expression `new Runner({runnertg, timeStamp})` has a type mismatch. `runnertg` is of type `std::string`, while the element `Runner::runnerTag` is of type `char[32]`.
2. The expression `runners[i] = new Runner({runnertg, timeStamp});` has another type mismatch. The element type of `runners` is `Runner`, while the expression `new Runner({runnertg, timeStamp})` is of type `Runner*`.
3. `runners[i]` is out-of-bound access. The size of `runners` is 0. The elements `runners[i]` for all values of `i` does not exist.
4. There is memory leak since there is no matching `delete` for each `new` for all code path.
5. Don't use `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the code you're using is old style C with some C++ STL code mixed in.  I will try and tackle a few issues one at at time.

`struct` is an abstract data type used (in general) to organise primitive data types.  While the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that the latter defaults all members to private and in this case is not functional, it's a good to cut these things of at the pass.

Secondly, an array of `char`s is cumbersome, messy and prone to error.  Try an `std::string` instead.

Finally, let's create a constructor taking our two parameters.

Thus:

```
#include <string>

class Runner {
public:
    std::string runnerTag;
    uint32_t ts;

    Runner(std::string, uint32_t);
};
```

Next thing.  Using an array index operator `[]` to access or modify an `std::vector` is dangerous and defeats the purpose of using a container and all the wonderful functionality that comes along with it.

Since you know for loops, let's try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::string runnertg = "testTrackTag01";
    uint32_t timeStamp = rand() % 100 + 1;
    Runner Runner(runnertg, timeStamp);
    runners.push_back(Runner);
}
```

At the end of your code, outside the scope of the main function, define the constructor as follows:

```
Runner::Runner(std::string rt,  uint32_t ts) {
    runnerTag = rt;
    ts = ts;
}
```

This should get you started.

Comment: I am getting errors on the line for runner = Runner(runnertg, timestamp) => No Viable Overloaded '='

Comment: runners.push_back(runner) => Use of undeclared identifier 'runner'

Comment: My C++ is pretty rusty.  I removed the assignment operator.  Can you try again?

Comment: Unknown type name 'runner'; did you mean 'Runner'?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Runner {
public:
    std::string runnerTag;
    uint32_t ts;
    
    Runner(std::string, uint32_t);
};

std::vector<Runner> runners;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::string runnertg = "testTrackTag01";
        uint32_t timeStamp = rand() % 100 + 1;
        runner Runner(runnertg, timeStamp);
        runners.push_back(runner);
    }
    return 0;
}

Runner::Runner(std::string rt, uint32_t tsi) {
    runnerTag = rt;
    ts = tsi;
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `std::string` to a `char` array like that. Change the type of the member variable `runnerTag` to `std::string`. Also, you are accessing vector elements that don't exist. Use `resize` to create them. Or better yet, use `emplace_back` to do both at once. Also, don't use `int` to iterate containers, but `std::size_t`. Also, don't use `rand()`, but the classes from the `<random>` header. That trick using % creates a non-uniform distribution.